# JAVA conditional logic to Impala query

Tags: if-statement, case, impala

I am having a conditional logic in JAVA which deals with databases, and I wanted to transform it to Impala. I am confused between using "CASE WHEN" and "IF" function in impala, so which of the below impala logics is better to use? and is it correct?

what is happening logically, is I am trying to fetch a column (**seller_id**) from the first table (**table_seller_inside**) if the main condition is true. And then check if the **seller_id** in null, then I will fetch from the other table (**table_seller_outside**)

JAVA logic:

```
if(temp_table.col_1!=null && !temp_table.col_2.trim().equals("") )
{
-> table_seller_inside.seller_id

    if(seller_id==null) 
    {
    -> table_seller_outside.seller_id
    }
}
```

Impala logic with CASE WHEN:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN temp_table.col_1 IS NOT NULL THEN 
            sel_in.seller_id as seller_id,
            sel_in.seller_name as seller_name,
            sel_in.seller_number as seller_num
            CASE WHEN (seller_id IS NULL) THEN
                sel_out.seller_id as seller_id,
                sel_out.seller_name as seller_name,
                sel_out.seller_number as seller_num,
            END
       END
FROM table_seller_inside sel_in,
     table_seller_outside sel_out
```

Impala logic with **IF**:

if(boolean condition, type ifTrue, type ifFalseOrNull)

```
SELECT if(temp_table.col_1 !="NULL", (sel_in.seller_id as seller_id,
                                     sel_in.seller_name as seller_name,
                                     sel_in.seller_number as seller_num),
            if(seller_id ="NULL", (sel_out.seller_id as seller_id,
                                   sel_out.seller_name as seller_name,
                                   sel_out.seller_number as seller_num)
FROM table_seller_inside sel_in,
     table_seller_outside sel_out
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sql. You need to mention joins or relationships between all associated tables.
Individual case when will work here. JAVA code is using if-else, so you can use wither case when or if().

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN temp_table.col_1 IS NOT NULL
                AND TRIM(temp_table.col_2)<>'' THEN sel_in.seller_id
           ELSE sel_out.seller_id
       END AS seller_id,
       CASE
           WHEN temp_table.col_1 IS NOT NULL
                AND TRIM(temp_table.col_2)<>'' THEN sel_in.seller_name
           ELSE sel_out.seller_name
       END AS seller_name ,
       CASE
           WHEN temp_table.col_1 IS NOT NULL
                AND TRIM(temp_table.col_2)<>'' THEN sel_in.seller_number
           ELSE sel_out.seller_number
       END AS seller_number
FROM table_seller_inside sel_in,
     table_seller_outside sel_out,
     temp_table
WHERE -- you need to give join condition/relations
sel_in.id = sel_out.id
  AND temp_table.key = sel_out.key
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. but what I actually have, is looking at the seller_id, and try to fetch (seller_id, seller_name, seller_number) as a bulk from the first table, then if the "seller_id" only is not exist in the first table, so I will take the bulk (seller_id, seller_name, seller_number) from the second table. And the joins are already specified in the original query.